# Quantatively identifying stocks to short when overall market starts to roll-over

Tags: portfolio-selection

Lets say we are seeing the market starting to top right now. Obviously, this leads to positioning on the short side. My issue is that I have a wide choice of stocks to short (overwhelmed by choice). The question then is which ones do I short that would maximise my return.

I currently use a crude method of Relative Strength to the underlying index (Stan Weinstein's method). This has been a profitable method for me but always felt I missed out!

Would appreciate very much if you could share your methodology of stock selection for shorting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: High beta stocks?

Comment: If you would know which stocks would maximize return, you would only short one (the one that is the maximum). Given you don't even know if the market is topping out, it will be the exact same question as going long, just that you face the problem of margin calls.

Comment: @AKdemy the question is "what quantative methodologies" that people use. It is not a question of whether the market is going to roll-over. Does that help clarify what I am after?

Comment: @rubikscube09 both high and low beta. The question is the what quantitative methodologies can one use to identify these opportunities.

Comment: I meant that by definition - if you know the whole market will roll over, then you should short high beta stocks because they will roll over even more.

Comment: @rubikscube09 - I analysed the ASX for the Feb20 sell-off. Surprisingly the declines to market lows did not correlate very well with Beta. In fact stocks with less than 1 Beta declined a lot more than ones win > 1 Beta. What to make of it, could you help?

Comment: It's a good question - one thing people look at is conditional beta, or upside/downside beta, e.g. beta conditional on the benchmark return being positive/negative.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to compute downside beta for this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

my take would be -- short the index.  I think when markets turn most people will sell the index and that will have been the best trade to be in.  Not sure you can rely on historical/statistical beta calculations when you hit a regime shift.